# Synonyme tags `sterilization`/`sterilisation`

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I just noticed that there are the tags

`sterilisation`*× 14*
Sterilization: any process that eliminates or kills all forms of life and other biological agents present in a specified region, such as a surface, a volume of fluid, medication, or in a compound such…
*3 asked this year*

`sterilization`*× 3*
*1 asked this year*

Could someone with enough rep please merge them and make one the synonyme of the other?

(out of curiosity: Is there a rule, whether tags should be spelled in American or British English?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I merged both tags to the british spelling (which was the more common one) and created a synonym.